# How to transfer field content of a view to a another view as a filter by clicking this content entry

Tags: views, 8

Example: 
View 1, field "city", content "Berlin"
By click on "Berlin" ->
opens View 2 (filter on "Berlin") in a separate block.
Is this feasible? How do you do that?

Btw: activating the second view in a block by a click - it seems impossible, isn't?
Which way: Make view per page and then -> into a block???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<a href="{{ url('view.testview.page_1', {'arg_0': field_example__value}) }}">{{field_example__value}}</a>
```

view-> Field-Content field_example _> overwrite output.

Works as well. Thx to 4*4 again.